# Unable to read from serial port. WaitCommEvent() never returns

Tags: c++, winapi, serial-port, readfile

I have to read bytes from serial port using win32 api but have not connected any device 
to the port to test so i write a byte in  the port and trying to read but `WaitCommEvent()` never
returns and program remains in waiting state.When i check to see if writing is done , i see is done but the problem is with `WaitCommEvent()`.

```
 HANDLE hPort;
 TCHAR *pcCommPort = TEXT("COM1");
 hPort = CreateFile( pcCommPort,GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,0,NULL);        

 if (hPort == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    MessageBox( hwnd , L"Error in opening serial port" , L"error" , MB_OK );
 else
    MessageBox( hwnd , L"Port opened" , L"successful" , MB_OK ); //This is displayed


 //Configuration

 DCB conf={0};
 conf.DCBlength = sizeof(conf);

 if(GetCommState(hPort, &conf))
{

  conf.ByteSize = 8;
  conf.Parity = NOPARITY;
  conf.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
  conf.fBinary = TRUE;
  conf.fParity = TRUE;

}

else
 MessageBox( hwnd , L"Cannot get comm state" , L"Oops" , MB_OK );

 if(!SetCommState(hPort, &conf))

 {
 MessageBox( hwnd , L"cannot set comm state" , L"Oops" , MB_OK );

 }


 //Timeout
 COMMTIMEOUTS commTimeout;

 if(GetCommTimeouts(hPort, &commTimeout))
 {

   COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts = { 0 };
   timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout         = 50; 
   timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant    = 50; 
   timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier  = 10; 

  }

 else
   MessageBox( hwnd , L"cannot get timeout" , L"Oops" , MB_OK );

 if(!SetCommTimeouts(hPort, &commTimeout))
    MessageBox( hwnd , L"cannot set timeout" , L"Oops" , MB_OK );


 //Writing
 char lpBuffer[] = "a";
 DWORD dNoOFBytestoWrite;       
 DWORD dNoOfBytesWritten = 0;     
 dNoOFBytestoWrite = sizeof(lpBuffer);

 WriteFile(hPort,lpBuffer,dNoOFBytestoWrite,&dNoOfBytesWritten,NULL);
 if(dNoOfBytesWritten == 1){
    MessageBox(NULL , L"Writing happened" , L"Attention" , MB_OK); //This is displayed
 }


//Reading
DWORD dwEventMask; 
SetCommMask(hPort, EV_RXCHAR);
WaitCommEvent(hPort, &dwEventMask, NULL); 

char TempChar; 
DWORD NoBytesRead;


ReadFile( hPort,&TempChar,sizeof(TempChar),&NoBytesRead, NULL);
CloseHandle(hPort);//Closing the Serial Port
```

What's wrong? Why can not i read ?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just issue the read?  Since you're in non-overlapped mode, it will block until the data is available, and it does it all with a single system call.  `WaitCommEvent` is only needed for the other events, `EV_RXCHAR` is quite pointless.

Comment: Also, the serial control configuration from `GetCommState` is probably not suitable for your program.  You need to set the baud rate and handshaking mode as appropriate for your device and not depend on the last user of the serial port to leave it in the right mode and needed speed.  Same with the other dozens of DCB options.

Comment: @Ben Voigt Thanks... I have seen in tutorials that using `EV_RXCHAR`.You mean its because of wrong configiration.How can i find the appropriate configuration for my device?And how can i set them to be appropriate for users who are going to use this app?

Comment: You want a serial device connected. You can short its RX and TX pin then you will receive data that you have sent for testing purpose.

Comment: @Ben Voigt You stated `WaitCommEvent()` is pointless with `EV_RXCHAR` .Think i have read that it saves data from serial port to a Windows buffer and then `ReadFile()` read bytes from the Windows buffer. Please,if i dont use `WaitCommEvent()` , how reading can be done?

Comment: @Code-Lover "Think i have read that it saves data from serial port to a Windows buffer"  This happens in the device's interrupt service routine, or IRP completion.  `WaitCommEvent()` is not involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I [...] have not connected any device to the port

A serial port "reads" bytes coming from the connected device.  You have no connected device.  Therefore no characters will ever come.

You can only read back the bytes that you yourself wrote if there is a loopback connection (making your computer its own connected device).  Some serial ports will support software-configured loopback, but C# doesn't provide any way to control this<sup>1</sup>.  Otherwise you will need a [hardware loopback connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback#Serial_interfaces) (which if you disable hardware handshaking, can be as simple as a single wire)

A final option would be a virtual serial port driver that connects to another application without involving any hardware at all.

---

<sup>1</sup> The Win32 API can enable and disable internal loopback, but it's unfortunately still neither standard nor universally supported.  See [`IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_MODEM_CONTROL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddser/ni-ntddser-ioctl_serial_set_modem_control).